# while() loop lets program crash, but there are no syntax errors or anything else

Tags: c, eclipse, mingw

I need to write a program, which let's the user type in a string and then proceeds to check the single char with `islower`,`isupper`, `isdigit`, but at the first loop for the string it always crashes and gives to `printfs` at a time after second turn.

Can somebody help please?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#ifndef MAIN_H_
#include "main.h"
#endif

int main()
{
    char cString[MAX];      //alle Felder auf NULL gesetzt für spätere Überprüfung ob Entertaste gedrückt wurde
    char cUebergabe[MAX];
    int iLauf=0;
    int iNULL=0;

    while(iLauf<MAX)
    {
        cString[iLauf]=iNULL;
        iLauf++;
    }
    iLauf=0;

    printf("geben sie maximal 20 Zahlen zur auswertung des String ein, bei der Eingabe von Enter ohne ein Symbol wird das Einlesen abgebrochen\n");

    while(iLauf<MAX)
    {
        printf("Geben Sie nun das %d . Zeichen ein\n",iLauf+1);

        scanf("%c",&cString[iLauf]);
        iLauf++;

        if(cString[iLauf-1]==iNULL)
        {
            iLauf=MAX;
        }
        else
            ;
    }
    strcpy(cUebergabe,cString);

    VerarbeitungAusgabe(cUebergabe, iNULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because we all have glass orbs with magical powers that can read your code that you haven't presented to us. Edit your question and add your code.

Comment: sorry I've sent it without knowing it

Comment: `#ifndef MAIN_H_` <-- include guards are usually in the header file, not in the file that includes it

Comment: `else;` <-- just omit the `else` if you don't need it. Also: you're calling `printf`'ing and then `scanf` for a single character. You may want to skip whitespace chars in the stdout buffer (`scanf(" %c", &char_var);` note the space before the format specifier)

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience but I've meant the second while with the Input

Comment: Value of MAX is 20

Comment: `cString` never appears to be terminated, btw. If that while loop doesn't get you, you're rolling the dice on that `strcpy(cUebergabe,cString)` doing so, which won't happen until you actually break from that loop. By what means are you slipping a null-octet into your input stream?

Comment: You don't have to set the contents of cString to zero and even if you still want to do it you can do so without a while loop using memset. Also instead of reading the input char for char why not read it all at once using fgets?

Comment: i tried it with fgets now but it still crashes after some chars

Comment: Run your program in a debugger so you can step through it and see what the variables contain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `%c` format specifier suppresses skipping of leading white space characters. And the new line (when the user presses *Enter*) is read in the next iteration after the number is read.

From the man page:

> Matches  a  sequence  of  characters whose length is specified by the maximum field width (default 1); the next pointer must be a pointer to char, and there must  be  enough  room for  all  the  characters (no terminating null byte is added).  The usual skip of leading white space is suppressed.  To skip white space first, use an explicit space in the  for‐ mat.

So just prepend a space:

```
scanf(" %c", &cString[iLauf]);
```

Also note, you can easily fill memory with zeroes with `memset`. So you can replace this:

```
while (iLauf < MAX) {
  cString[iLauf] = iNULL;
  iLauf++;
}
iLauf = 0;
```

with this:

```
memset(cString, 0, sizeof(cString));
```

or even this:

```
char cString[MAX] = {0};
```